# Entity framework database first mappers issue

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, database-first

I am using VS2010, with SQL server 2008 R2.

I am a complete beginner at both c# and Entity Framework.

The issue I am having in the example below is that when I try to get the questions associated with a particular tab The SQL produced is incorrect. I think it has something to do with the fact that I have A Tab_ID foreign key on 2 tables referencing the same Field with the same name?

However when I try to get the tabs associated with Checksheets the SQL produced is correct. I have done everything exactly the same but it has produced different results?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Below I have attached the method used and the out put as well as the DB relationship model and the mappers that I have used.

**Tabs Associated with CheckSheets (works as expected)**

```
    public IQueryable<CheckSheetTab> getTabs(int checkSheetId)
    {
        //includes the foreign key information when returning Tab
        var allReturnInfo = CheckSheetTab.Include(x => x.Tab);
        var result = allReturnInfo.Where(p => p.CheckSheet_ID == checkSheetId);
        result = result.OrderBy(x => x.Order_ID);
        return result;
    }
```

SQL PRODUCED

```
    {SELECT 
[Extent1].[Table_ID] AS [Table_ID], 
[Extent1].[Tab_ID] AS [Tab_ID], 
[Extent1].[CheckSheet_ID] AS [CheckSheet_ID], 
[Extent1].[Order_ID] AS [Order_ID], 
[Extent2].[Tab_ID] AS [Tab_ID1], 
[Extent2].[Tab_Desc] AS [Tab_Desc]
FROM  [dbo].[tbl_CheckSheet_Tabs] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_Tabs] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Tab_ID] = [Extent2].[Tab_ID]}
```

**Questions Associated with Tabs (Does not work)**

```
        public IQueryable<TabQuestion> getQuestions(int tabId)
    {
        //includes the foreign key information when returning Tab
        var allReturnInfo = TabQuestion.Include(x => x.Question);
        // NOTE FOR SOME REASON THIS IS NOT CREATING THE CORRECT SQL!!!!!!!!!
        var result = allReturnInfo.Where(p => p.Tab_ID == tabId);
        result = result.OrderBy(x => x.Order_ID);
        return result;
    }
```

SQL PRODUCED - EXTENT 3 is the issue and I cant see why it is produced.

```
{SELECT 
[Extent1].[Table_ID] AS [Table_ID], 
[Extent1].[Question_ID] AS [Question_ID], 
[Extent1].[Tab_ID] AS [Tab_ID], 
[Extent1].[Order_ID] AS [Order_ID], 
[Extent2].[Question_ID] AS [Question_ID1], 
[Extent2].[Question_Desc] AS [Question_Desc], 
[Extent2].[Parent_ID] AS [Parent_ID], 
[Extent3].[Tab_Tab_ID] AS [Tab_Tab_ID]
FROM   [dbo].[tbl_Tab_Questions] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_Questions] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Question_ID] = [Extent2].[Question_ID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_Questions] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[Question_ID] = [Extent3].[Question_ID]}
```

I have created the following database:
(I dont yet have 10 reputation to post images but the link is below)
**https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPwKw.jpg**

I have mappers set up for the Tables as follows:

```
    class CheckSheetTabConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<CheckSheetTab>
{
    public CheckSheetTabConfiguration() : base()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.Table_ID);

        Property(p => p.Tab_ID)
            .HasColumnName("Tab_ID");

        Property(p => p.CheckSheet_ID)
            .HasColumnName("CheckSheet_ID");

        Property(p => p.Order_ID)
            .HasColumnName("Order_ID");

        //add the foreign key constraint
        HasRequired(p => p.Tab)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.Tab_ID);

        HasRequired(p => p.CheckSheet)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.CheckSheet_ID);

        ToTable("tbl_CheckSheet_Tabs");
    }

}

class TabQuestionConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<TabQuestion>
{
    public TabQuestionConfiguration()
        : base()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.Table_ID);

        Property(p => p.Tab_ID)
            .HasColumnName("Tab_ID");

        Property(p => p.Question_ID)
            .HasColumnName("Question_ID");

        Property(p => p.Order_ID)
            .HasColumnName("Order_ID");

        //add the foreign key constraint
        HasRequired(p => p.Question)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.Question_ID);

        HasRequired(p => p.Tab)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.Tab_ID);

        ToTable("tbl_Tab_Questions");
    }
}
```

And I have the classes set up as follows:

```
public class CheckSheetTab
{
    public Int32 Table_ID { get; set; }
    public Int32 Tab_ID { get; set; }
    public Int32 CheckSheet_ID { get; set; }
    public Int32 Order_ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Tab Tab { get; set; }
    public virtual CheckSheet CheckSheet { get; set; }
}

public class TabQuestion
{
    public Int32 Table_ID { get; set; }
    public Int32 Question_ID { get; set; }
    public Int32 Tab_ID { get; set; }
    public Int32 Order_ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Question Question { get; set; }  
    public virtual Tab Tab { get; set; }  
}
```

***Tab Configuration**

```
class TabConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Tab>
{
    public TabConfiguration() : base()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.Tab_ID);

        Property(p => p.Tab_Desc)
            .HasColumnName("Tab_Desc");

        ToTable("tbl_Tabs");
    }
}
```

***Question Configuration**

```
class QuestionConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Question>
{
    public QuestionConfiguration() : base()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.Question_ID);

        Property(p => p.Question_Desc)
            .HasColumnName("Question_Desc");

        Property(p => p.Parent_ID)
            .HasColumnName("Parent_ID");

        ToTable("tbl_Questions");
    }
}
```

***CheckSheet Configuration**

```
class CheckSheetConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<CheckSheet>
{
    public CheckSheetConfiguration() : base()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.CheckSheet_ID);

        Property(p => p.CheckSheet_Desc)
            .HasColumnName("CheckSheet_Desc");

        Property(p => p.Tab_Count)
            .HasColumnName("Tab_Count");

        ToTable("tbl_CheckSheets");
    }
}
```

**Base Classes**

```
    public class CheckSheet
{
    public int CheckSheet_ID { get; set; }
    public String CheckSheet_Desc { get; set; }
    public int Tab_Count { get; set; }
    public List<Tab> tabs { get; set; }
}

public class Tab
{
    public int Tab_ID { get; set; }
    public string Tab_Desc { get; set; }
    public List<Question> questions { get; set; }
}

public class Question
{
    public int Question_ID { get; set; }
    public int Question_Desc { get; set; }
    public int Parent_ID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The method that prodeuces the incorrect sql above has been updated

Comment: Please post the definition and configuration of Tab?

Comment: Having two columns with the same name in different tables is fine. It seems it's trying to fulfill your where requirement.

It seems your query will request all data and then filter it on the client. Could you try a more pure Linq approach:
   `return from tabQuestion in TabQuestion
       include Question
       where tabQuestion.Tab_ID = tabId
       order by Order_ID;`

Comment: @Rob Epstein, Tab configuration added.

Comment: @MrFox, I am not very proficient at linq but I tried what you have outlined above and VS is telling me that it must end in a select.

Comment: Your `Question` configuration would help as well as it appears there is  a parent/child relationship defined in it that is causing the specific query you provided.

Comment: I have added both Question and checkSheet configuration. I should also point out that the SQL output is the allReturnInfo value not the result value. The function crashes out on that line because Tab_Tab_ID does not exist as a column in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the cause of the error, it is something so simple, I was trying to populate a string to an int, My error handling was not up to scratch so skipped it instead of logging it and as a result the error manifested itself as incorrectly produced SQL.

Issue:

```
public class Question
{
    public int Question_ID { get; set; }
    public int Question_Desc { get; set; }
    public int Parent_ID { get; set; }
}
```

Resoultion

```
public class Question
{
    public int Question_ID { get; set; }
    public string Question_Desc { get; set; }
    public int Parent_ID { get; set; }
}
```